# Get authenticated user information in Azure Api App

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, azure, azure-api-apps

**Context**

I have a Azure Api App set as "Public (authenticated)" and have enabled Facebook identity. My Api App is protected and I am able authenticated with FB. In the Api App, I want to get the authenticated user information such as login provider, token and email to save in a database.

**Problem**

I can't find any documentation on how to obtain this info. I followed [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/) article and tried

```
    var runtime = Runtime.FromAppSettings(Request);
    var user = runtime.CurrentUser;
    TokenResult token = user.GetRawTokenAsync("facebook").Result;
    var name = (string)token.Claims["name"];
    var email = (string)token.Claims["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"];
```

I've made the changes to the apiapp.json file to allow facebook authentication `"authentication": [{"type": "facebook"}]` but it times out at `GetRawTokenAsync` when remote debugging the Api App.

Looking at other blogs/articles/posts, following is another way by referencing additional assemblies "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile"

```
    var user = (MobileAppUser)this.User;
    var facebookCredentials = user.GetIdentityAsync<FacebookCredentials>().Result;
```

But this also doesn't work as `this.user` is of type `WindowsPrincipal` user when remote debugging my Api App. And apparently "Microsoft.Azure.AppService.ApiApps.Service" is the only reference an Azure Api App needs.

Am I missing something? Seems like a basic scenario to get the authenticated user in a Api App web service.

Comment: Did you get past this?  Your initial code looks correct.  You shouldn't need anything in apiapp.json.  Could you share the signature of the method that contains the code?  Is it async or sync?

Comment: Nope still have this problem. What do you mean by I shouldn't need anything in the apiapp.json? Not even the "authentication" property? Here's the method signature `public IEnumerable<string> Get()`

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work. When calling `GetRawTokenAsync` method we must `await`. Using `Result` or `Wait` from the `Task` object doesn’t work and times out. This is still unclear to me why, perhaps a framework bug?